# Existence and uniqueness and numerical solution of a system of second order nonlinear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, computational-mathematics

The following system of two non-linear second order ODEs comes up in my research:

\begin{align*}
& x''(t)+a_1 x'(t)+a_2 x(t)^\alpha+a_3\frac{1}{1+e^t}+a_4=0\\
& x(t)^\beta\Big(y''(t)+b_1 y'(t)+b_2\frac{1}{1+e^t}+b_3\Big)+b_4 y(t)+b_5 x(t)=0
\end{align*}
subject to the following conditions:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t)=A\\
& x'(t_0)=y'(t_0)=0\\
& y(t_0)=y_0
\end{align*}
where the coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5$ and parameters $\alpha,\beta, y_0, A$ are given and $t_0$ is to be solved for. My questions are:

1. How do I prove the existence and uniqueness theorem for such a system?
2. How can I solve the system numerically? (I'm assuming an analytical solution does not exist) Please note that $t_0$ needs to be solved for as well.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where does this system come from? It may have no solution at all... You are fixing 3 conditions for $y$ and 2 conditions for $x$, which is not standard for a second order system.

Comment: It comes from a dynamic programming problem. Please note that $t_0$ is also a variable, so there are indeed 5 conditions but there are also 5 variables.